# groupby().mean() don't work under for loop

Tags: python

I have a dictionary named c with objects as dataframe, each dataframe has 3 columns: 'year' 'month' & 'Tmed' , I want to calculate the monthly mean values of Tmed for each year, I used

```
for i in range(22) : c[i].groupby(['year','month']).mean().reset_index()
```

This returns

```
  year   month  Tmed
0 2018   12     14.8
2 2018   12     12.0
3 2018   11     16.1
5 2018   11     9.8
6 2018   11     9.8
9 2018   11     9.3

4425 rows × 3 columns
```

The index is not as it should be, and for the 11th month of 2018 for example, there should be only one row but as you see the dataframe has more than one.

I tried the code on a single dataframe and it gave the wanted result :

```
c[3].groupby(['year','month']).mean().reset_index()

     year   month   Tmed
0    1999     9    23.950000
1    1999    10    19.800000
2    1999    11    12.676000
3    1999    12    11.012000
4    2000     1     9.114286
5    2000     2    12.442308
6    2000     3    13.403704
7    2000     4    13.803846
8    2000     5    17.820000
.        
.
.
218  2018     6    21.093103
219  2018     7    24.977419
220  2018     8    26.393103
221  2018     9    24.263333
222  2018    10    19.069565
223  2018    11    13.444444
224  2018    12    13.400000

225 rows × 3 columns
```

I need to put for loop because I have many dataframes, I can't figure out the issue, any help would be gratefull.

Comment: is there the same year and month is multiple items of the dictionary

Comment: Can you clarify, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a reason why your code should fail. I tried below and got the required results:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def getRandomDataframe():
    rand_year = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2010, 2011,size=(50, 1)), columns=list('y'))
    rand_month = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 13,size=(50, 1)), columns=list('m'))
    rand_value = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100,size=(50, 1)), columns=list('v'))
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['year', 'month', 'value'])
    df['year'] = rand_year
    df['month'] = rand_month
    df['value'] = rand_value

    return df


def createDataFrameDictionary():
    _dict = {}
    length = 3

    for i in range(length):
        _dict[i] = getRandomDataframe()

    return _dict

c = createDataFrameDictionary()

for i in range(3):
    c[i] = c[i].groupby(['year','month'])['value'].mean().reset_index()


# Check results
print(c[0])
```

Comment: Hello calvin,I don't want to print the result actually,  I want to apply the groupby().mean() to the dataframe, I don't know why it fails too, the groupby().mean()  does not give the result it should give under for loop, but when I run it on a single data frame or assign the result to a new datafram it works.

Comment: #anash: you don't have to print the results, I edited my answer which doesn't print but updates. In the end, to check the results I am printing the dictionary dataframe! thanks!

Comment: Hello Calvin, thanks for the answer , I could update the datafram and have the wanted result under for loop without having to assign results to another datafram, What solved the issue is the ['values'] column which I didn't add in my code  c[i].groupby(['year','month']).mean().reset_index()  , Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if  the year, month combo repeats in different dataframes which could be the reason for the repeat.

In your scenario, it may be a good idea to collect the groupby.mean results for each dataframe in another dataframe and do a groupby mean again on the new dataframe

Comment: Hello mvinayakam, Thanks for the answer. I assigned the groupby().mean result to another dataframe and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(22): 
    main_df  = pd.concat([main_df, c[i].groupby(['year','month']).mean().reset_index()])
print(main_df.groupby(['year','month']).mean())
```

Comment: Hello Jeril, thanks for the reply. I tried the code, it gave me the following error : TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: there was an typo, can you check now